# Problem with sorting, alpha-style bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

When I compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noendperiod,
               fontsize=11pt, 
               twoside, 
               a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber, autolang=hyphen, style=ieee-alphabetic, 
            maxnames=10, dashed=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bad-bib.bib}
@book{cohn-algebra,
    Author = {Paul Moritz Cohn},
    Title = {Universal Algebra},
    Publisher = {D. Reidel Publishing Company},
    Year = {1981}}

@book{cohn-algebra-gra,
    Author = {Paul Moritz Cohn},
    Title = {Basic Algebra: groups, rings, and fields},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    isbn =  {978-1-4471-1060-6},
    Year = {2003}}

@book{cohn,
    Author = {Donald L. Cohn},
    Title = {Measure Theroy},
    Publisher = {Birkh{\"a}use, Boston},
    Year = {1980}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bad-bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first}
This is the document. \cite{cohn-algebra,cohn-algebra-gra,cohn}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I have an error in the sort of the bibliography. Any help?

Comment: pdflatex, biber pdflatex, pdflatex runs without error here, please show the full error message from your log

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Not quite: with the OP's setup, `Coh03` is placed before `Coh80`.

Comment: @Mico I  got no _error_  (I didn't look at the output)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Good point. I'll add a comment to point out that what the OP was getting isn't really an *error*; instead, it's an unexpected form of output because he/she failed to specify an important `biblatex` option.

Comment: You wrote, "I have an error in the sort of the bibliography". Actually, the sorting order you got is not an *error*, at least not in the sense of one or more programs not running correctly. Instead, what you got is the consequence of failing to specify your desired sorting order. It just so turns out that the default sorting order and your desired sorting don't coincide. As my answer shows, what you need to do is add a `biblatex` option that specifies *your* preferred sorting order.

Comment: I agree. I should edit the question. In fact, it's not an error: it's my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the biblatex option `sorting=nyt` -- name(s), then year, then title. If you add this option and do a full recompile cycle (latex-biber-latex), you'll get the following sorted bibliography:

[image]

Observe that D. L. Cohn now comes before the two P. M. Cohn entries (since "Donald" precedes "Paul", at least alphabetically) and that `Coh80` now comes before `Coh03`.